# Backing out actual dates from YEARFRAC

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two dates: `8/31/2023` and `3/31/2043` in A1 and A2.

I have calculated the fraction of years using `=YEARFRAC(A1,A2)` in A2 as `=YEARFRAC(A1,A2)` as `19.58333333`.

I'm trying to add this number to a different date.

However, as a check, adding to the original `8/31/2023` in A1 as follows:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1)+INT(A3),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))+MOD(A3,1)*360
```

produces `3/29/2043`. This is close but not exact as I expected `3/31/2043`?

Comment: Instead of `360` using `365` would return exactly `3/31/2043`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya  that's better what what if that's a leap year i.e., the date is `3/31/2044`

Comment: You are getting an inconsistent value because you are using `US (NASD) 30/360 count basis` which automatically considers a last day of the month as 30th as always even if its 31st, and when its a leap year it makes 30th as well, if i am not wrong, also for leap year the adjustments is .25 that is `365.25`

Comment: i do not disagree.  i have to use `30/360` as that's one of the quoting convention for bonds.  is there a way to replace 365 or 366 in more robust fashion?

Comment: not sure may be using the `EU` convention would work.

Comment: `=EDATE(A1,12*A3)` gets you back, exactly, to 31-Mar-2043 (and with only 1 function, instead of 6)

Comment: You're not using YEARFRAC correctly. It has a third argument (base) which defaults to base 30 days a month/360 days a year. You have a start date greater than 30, so you should use a different base: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/yearfrac-function-3844141e-c76d-4143-82b6-208454ddc6a8

Comment: @spectral instance, that would only work in case of whole months difference only.

Comment: @P.b  so this is for a bond and they typically have [30/360 day count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention#30/360_methods).  The `8/31/2023` is the actual date when the bond is effective.  Not sure why would i use a different base or date count.  Your comment on EDATE is exactly correct, on the other hand

Comment: In that case you need to clarify what day 31 st of a month is if you use base 30/360.

Comment: Since you use base 30, changing the start date and/or end date to 31 or 30 calculates to the same outcome. That being said. 31st is not to be used in combination of YEARFRAC base 30. You can workaround the start day being greater than 30, but with an end date greater than 30, you simply shouldn't use YEARFRAC like that.
Also, I'm still not convinced why you should use YEARFRAC in the first place. Why are you adding it to a different date?

Comment: @P.b  sure, this may derail this thread, but there is a concept of [WAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted-average_life) which is using `30/360` basis. so the bond end date called Maturity will be effectively earlier than the actual end date which i'm trying to arrive to using 'YEARFRAC' which equals WAL i get elsewhere.  I hope this is not making things more cloudy